# I created a grid(divs) from user input in jQuery, how to reset and start again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JS and JQuery at the moment and I am making a drawing game, now I need to be able to reset the game.

The user gets prompted at the beginning and selects grid size. Now when I reset, the user gets asked again but I cannot find a way to remove my existing cells properly.

I think maybe it is to do with how I'm organising my functions?

Any help would be amazing, I put two of my options in there at the bottom of the script.

Thanks in advance

http://codepen.io/Middi/pen/rrgqOv

```
$(document).ready(function() { 


createGrid();

}); 


function createGrid() {


  // if('.cell'.length > 0) {
  //
  //   $(.cell).remove()
  //
  // }




var boxes = prompt("select a grid between 2 - 128?","0");


var x = parseInt(boxes);

  if(x > 128) {

    alert("must be between 1-128");
  }

    else {


    }

    for(elementCount = 0; elementCount < x; elementCount++) {

      $('#container').append('<div class="col"></div>');



    }

    for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < x; columnCount++) {

      $('.col').append('<div class="cell"></div>');

      $(".cell").width(572/x);
      $(".cell").height(572/x);
    }






    $('.cell').mouseenter(function () {
       $(this).addClass('highlight');

   });


}





function clearButton() {
  $(".cell").removeClass('highlight');

}

// --------- OPTION ONE ---------- //

// function resetButton() {
//   $('#container').remove('.cell');

// }



// --------  OPTION TWO ---------- //

function resetButton() {
  createGrid();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove all .cell

```
//like $('#container').empty()

function removeCell() {
   $('#container').empty()
}

function resetButton() {
    removeCell();
    createGrid();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it irritated me for so long!

Answer (score 0):

Your resetButton only creates new grid, meaning it redimensionates your existing grid... if you want it to clear it before resizing, you can invoke the clearButton() function before resizing.

```
function resetButton() {
  clearButton();
  createGrid();
}
```

I tested in your example and it did the trick!
Was that what you wanted?